# why the while loop runs once?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

the following code is only running once , while the number of times it should run is 4 , any help ?

**PHP::**

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");

require_once("config.php");

if(isset($_GET["m"])) {

    $dirname = "images/main/";
    $arr = array();

    $conn = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

    if(!$conn) {
        echo "Error connecting to database";
        exit();
    }
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name_ FROM projects")) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($n);
        //$stmt->store_result();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows == 0) {
            echo "No Projects";
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
            exit();
        }else {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $dirname = $dirname . $row["name_"] . "/";
                $images = glob($dirname . "*.*", GLOB_BRACE);
                foreach($images as $image) {
                    echo $row["name_"];
                    echo$result->num_rows;  // returns 4 !!!!
                    $image = base64_encode($image);
                    //$arr[] = $image;
                    array_push($arr, $image);
                    $image = "";
                }
            }
            echo json_encode($arr);  // returns 1 json row oonly
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    exit();

}

?>
```

num rows return 4 so why it runs or loops for one time only ?

I am trying to get images from images folder to echo it back

**FIX::**

according to jhilgeman's answer I added this part to the end of foreach:

```
$dirname = "images/main/";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say that it's looping correctly, but the problem is this line:

```
$dirname = $dirname . $row["name_"] . "/";
```

Each time you loop, you're APPENDING the $row["name"] value to whatever $dirname is. So let's say that you get 4 rows back like this:

```
name
----
houses
boats
computers
animals
```

At the beginning of the loop, let's say $dirname is just "/images/". So the first loop would change $dirname to be:

```
/images/houses/
```

Then the second loop would change it to be:

```
/images/houses/boats/
```

The third loop would then make it:

```
/images/houses/boats/computers/
```

And finally the fourth loop:

```
/images/houses/boats/computers/animals/
```

So unless you're expecting the $dirname to be appended that way, you probably want to instead REPLACE $dirname instead of appending to it each time.

Try this instead for your loop:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $images_dirname = $dirname . $row["name_"] . "/";
  $images = glob($images_dirname . "*.*", GLOB_BRACE);

  foreach($images as $image) {
    ...etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks , it worked , i don't know how i couldn't figure out such a point !